# gvim font settings in windows

Tags: windows, vim, fonts, gvim

I want to use anti-aliasing and hinting with gvim on windows. On my *nix box I just added the following to my .Xresources file:

```
Xft.antialias:  true
Xft.rgba:       rgb
Xft.hinting:    true
Xft.hintstyle:  hintfull
```

How do I achieve the same in windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim doesn't use Xft on Windows; instead the native Windows font rendering is used.

The subpixel antialiasing is called "ClearType". In Windows 7 it is on by default, and adjustable through *Control Panel → Appearance and Personalization → Display → Adjust ClearType text*. On Windows XP, use [ClearType Tuner](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartypepowertoy.mspx). Font hinting is always enabled.

Comment: Oh, I've turned off ClearType because I didn't like it. Can I enable it only for gvim?

Comment: No. (It's technically possible but you would need to patch Gvim.) If ClearType looks bad to you, try adjusting contrast in CT Tuner.