# Why is my Gvim font so ugly and grainy under Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, vim, fonts, gvim

I use Gvim on Linux and Windows. On Windows 7 Gvim just looks ugly. Mainly because of the font. The fonts looks very grainy and poorly rendered. I tried a few different fonts.

```
guifont=Inconsolta:h12:cDEFAULT
```

Why is that Fonts rendering so bad and how can I improve the look and feel of Gvim in Windows 7?

[image: Click for a bigger version]

(click the image for a bigger version)

Comment: You need to tell us at least the font(s) you're using (`:set guifont?`), and for such visual complaints, a screenshot comparison would help. "Ugly" is very subjective.

Comment: not enough reputation to upload a picture

Comment: Upload to an image hoster, and place the URL here; we'll edit that in.

Comment: With the cmder Console Emulator my vim looks as nice as on Linux. The Fonts are renderd much better. http://bliker.github.io/cmder/

Answer (score 1):

From here: 
[gvim font settings in windows](https://superuser.com/questions/311260/gvim-font-settings-in-windows)

> The subpixel antialiasing is called "ClearType". In Windows 7 it is on
>   by default, and adjustable through Control Panel → Appearance and
>   Personalization → Display → Adjust ClearType text. On Windows XP, use
>   ClearType Tuner. Font hinting is always enabled.

I've struggled with horrible gvim font rendering for years and finally decided to resolve it. I tried this out and this appears to work. All of the graininess of gvim went away after turning ClearType on and walking through the calibration walkthrough. All of our computers had ClearType disabled resulting in this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The default GVim text renderer is [GDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Device_Interface). If you have [DirectX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX) support (modern graphics card) you can use that instead. Anyway it is the only available alternative renderer right now. To use it see the ['renderoptions' option](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27renderoptions%27). Playing with the various directx behavior settings can improve that situation. I have found `taamode` settings to be the very noticeable & effective. Make sure to try them with various, non-rasterized, fonts. See more [in the help page](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27renderoptions%27).